# Docker exec with dollar variable

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm trying to run a command inside a Docker container with an environment variable, but I can't figure out the right syntax.

I can see the variable is set correctly:

```
$ docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 env | grep FOO
FOO=bar
```

I thought double dollar sign (`$$`) would work here but that prints a weird number.

```
$ docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 echo $FOO

$ docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 echo '$FOO'
$FOO
$ docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 echo \$FOO
$FOO
$ docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 echo $$FOO
24136FOO
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Facts

- `docker exec` runs an executable, not a command in a shell.
- In your cases the executable is `echo`.
- `echo` does not care about environment variables. When it gets `$FOO`, it prints `$FOO`.

---

#### Your attempts explained

1. ```
   docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 echo $FOO
   ```

   `docker` is a command. `exec`, `-e`, `FOO=bar`, `cfdb72_db_1`, and `echo` are command lines arguments the command will get. `$FOO` is unquoted, so your current shell expands it. The variable does not exist in the current shell (or maybe it exists but it contains all blanks or an empty string). `"$FOO"` would make the shell pass exactly one additional argument after `echo`. Unquoted `$FOO` [can expand to zero or more words](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618); in your particular case the number is zero. So it's as if you run:

   ```
   docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 echo
   ```

   The command to run in the container is sole `echo`. Sole `echo` prints exactly one newline.
2. ```
   docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 echo '$FOO'
   ```

   `$FOO` is single-quoted, the shell does not treat it as a variable to expand. The shell removes the quotes before passing the literal `$FOO` string as an argument to `docker`. The `docker` executable receives `exec`, `-e`, `FOO=bar`, `cfdb72_db_1`, `echo`, and `$FOO` as arguments. The command to run in the container is like `echo $FOO`, but there is no shell to expand `$FOO`. In fact I shouldn't write `echo $FOO` because this string does not exist as a single entity that has to be split. Your shell has already identified words in the original command, it passed `echo` and `$FOO` as separate arguments to `docker` and from then on they are treated as distinct members of some array. Consider the command to run in the container as `echo` `$FOO` rater than `echo $FOO`. In the container `echo` is run directly and it receives `$FOO` literally, so it prints `$FOO` (followed by a newline character because this is how `echo` works by default).
3. ```
   docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 echo \$FOO
   ```

   `$` is escaped, the shell does not treat `$FOO` in `\$FOO` as a variable to expand. The only thing the shell does is removing the backslash before passing the literal `$FOO` string as an argument to `docker`. The rest happens exactly like above.
4. ```
   docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 echo $$FOO
   ```

   `$$` is unquoted, the current shell expands it. It's a special parameter that expands to the decimal process ID of the shell. Apparently it is `24136` in your example. After the expansion `$$FOO` becomes `24136FOO`. The command to run in the container is like `echo 24136FOO` (and again think of `echo` `24136FOO` rather than `echo 24136FOO`). In effect `echo` prints `24136FOO` (and a newline character).

---

#### Solution

If you want `$FOO` to be expanded, you need a shell that will expand it:

```
docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 sh -c 'echo "$FOO"'
```

Now the command to run in the container is `sh` with arguments `-c` and `echo "$FOO"`.

Notes:

- `$FOO` is [properly double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) when the code is interpreted by the new shell inside the container. There are two shells, two levels of quoting. The single-quotes are for the current shell; the double-quotes are for the new shell.
- In most shells (and in most implementations of `sh`) `echo` is a builtin. In all your examples `echo` was a standalone executable (`/bin/echo` or whatever inside the container). The two should be (mostly) equivalent. In general however keep in mind a command with some name in a shell and a command with the same name invoked directly are not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You're exec'ing into the container an echo command. The echo command doesn't expand the `$`, that's the job of a shell. You're also running the docker command in a shell that will expand variables if you don't escape them from that shell, so docker would never even see the `$`, let alone the process inside the container.

To run a shell and avoid having `$FOO` expanded in the shell parsing the `docker` command, you can use `/bin/sh` inside the container, and single quotes on the commandline:

```
docker exec -e FOO=bar cfdb72_db_1 /bin/sh -c 'echo "$FOO"'
```